# Which renderer will be called if we have multiple renderer for same control?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin Forms app where I am struck with 2 issues

**First:**
I have my custom button renderer and it is working fine. Now I have included reference of another project which have it's own button render. In this case there are two renderer for button. Which will be called and how??

**Second:**
What if I want to make use of both of the renders?

**What I have tried:**
Inherited my renderer from the renderer of the referenced project, but it won't work.I am confused with registration of this two renderers.How to register my renderer if inherited from other one.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, likely whichever the compiler finds first will be the one which is used. However this is only based on observations, I haven't found any documentation to back this up.

If this is something you have to support, what you can do is remove the assembly attribute from the renderers in the referenced project and move them into the target project i.e.

Move the following from the Renderer:

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CutomButton), typeof(MyApp.Renderers.CustomButtonRenderer))]

To say, the iOS Target project and place it on top of the AppDelegate class.

This means you will have several of these lines in the AppDelegate, but you can control which renderer you use i.e. ones in the library (if you can ensure they don't contain the above decoration) or ones in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, always create a new class that inherit XF's control, so that the control and renderer would be one-one relationship.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Button), typeof(MyApp.Renderers.CustomButtonRenderer))] //bad

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CutomButton), typeof(MyApp.Renderers.CustomButtonRenderer))] //good
```